Stable homology of general linear groups
For what class of rings $R$, is the stable homology (with various choices of coefficients) of $GL_n(R)$ known? Borel computed it rationally for number rings, Quillen computed it for finite fields. Are there other large classes of examples?

It is done in https://www-jstor-org.sheffield.idm.oclc.org/stable/1971200?seq=1 for $R$ a PID with very general coefficients.

@JD1874 That link appears to be behind a university login. What paper were you linking to?

@DanRamras apologies, this should work https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971200. Twisted homological stability for the general linear groups by Dwyer

Dwyer's paper is about homological stability. It does not contain a computation of a stable homology group.

With twisted reduced polynomial coefficients (given by evaluating a reduced polynomial functor on fg free $R$-modules), it wanishes for each ring $R$, thanks to Betley or Scorichenko. The questions with constant and twisted coefficients have rather different flavour.
